# reusing text with multiple components of same type in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

```js
Vue.component('home',{
  template: '<p>{{homeText}}</p>',
  data: function(){
    return{
      homeText:"Welcome"  
    }
  }
})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<home></home>
<home></home>
<home></home>

</div>
```

Currently I am hardcoding the value in the data function.

I am trying to reproduce result to be

`Welcome
to 
this page!!`

I want to be able to add different text to my home component. In examples and tutorials all i find is how to change numeric values. I want to know how I can pass custom text to these components.

My goal is to build a section component and then pass custom text to each component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `data`, define a prop named `homeText` and then pass custom text to the component wherever it's used:

```js
Vue.component('home',{
  template: '<p>{{homeText}}</p>',
  props: ['homeText']
})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<home home-text="welcome"></home>
<home home-text="to"></home>
<home home-text="this page"></home>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the linking between homeText and home-text? How does vue know to look for home-text? we never define home-text anywhere.

Comment: CamelCase props are converted kebab-case in the template. see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any variable to a component by using `v-bind`.

```
<MyComponent v-bind:myText="homeText"/>
```

Then this will appear as a prop in the component, so be sure to map it out.

```
props: {
     myText: String
}
```

Then you can access it as though it were data.

You may also see `v-bind:myVariable="whatever"` written has `:myVariable="whatever"`, which is the same thing.

Comment: You may have interchanged `myText` and `homeText`

Comment: @RalphChristopherGalido Good catch, you're absolutely right. Fixed.